# Fancy python docs in Spyder

Tags: python, documentation, spyder

I'm writing some documentation in Python using Spyder as IDE.

For example I have a function:

```
def TestFunction(args1,args2):
    """
    General Description

    Args:
        args1: describing
        args2: describing
    Return:
        data
    """
       ...code here....
```

Is it possible to make the documentation more fancy with words in bold or italics etc etc.
Any reference?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot find any answer, but did you try to use markdown?

Comment: mmh Honestly no. Can I use markdown in the description of the function like I posted? I don't want to make great changes...

Comment: I don't knoe since I couldn't find an answer, but you can try it out atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) It's possible to make your docs fancier by following the conventions of Restructured text. You can find its specification [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use numpy a lot, so I installed [numpydoc](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 
and it enabled 'automatic connections' in the help under preferences.

[image: help, automatic connections]

It does a nice job
[image]